# What's the term for an unsecured wifi network that requires logging in through a browser?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for the kind of wifi network that is **open** (doesn't have WEP or WPA protection or whatever; you can connect to it freely), but which requires you to log in (through a local web page) before you can use the internet?

This is the kind of set-up used in a lot of airports, cafés, and on my company's "guest" wifi network (for visitors).

Is there a short name for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)" means precisely this.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Hotspot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_%28Wi-Fi%29) the word you're looking for?

Comment: A hotspot may or may not be open and may or may not require you to log in.

Comment: Hotspot is good, but it's usually the general term for open networks that are either free or commercial, with or without a login.